# What is DeployDirSuffix for?

Tags: c#, csproj

In a `.csproj` file, there is a `DeployDirSuffix` node. The default value is the project name.

What does this setting do? Upon changing it (while renaming a project) I did not notice any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node is only there for Smart Device projects.

It sets the directory when deploying to a device via USB (or other means). You can find this setting via **project properties**, **Device** menu, **Output file folder** field.